# WordPress Find and Replace in the Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

A quick overview: We're trying to convert some very long standing (7+ year old) WordPress Multisite installations from Subdomain to Subdirectory. Changing the `wp-config.php` and `.htaccess` is all well and good. But some of these installations have well over 1000 sites, and littered throughout the database can have an immense number of instances of `abc.multisite.com`.

I'm trying to find the best way to automate the conversion of `abc.multisite.com` to `multisite.com/abc`, of course without it affecting `123abc.multisite.com` leading to `123multisite.com/abc`.

All of the find/replace plugins I've seen that could do this only do a single search at a time, and I've got thousands of records to replace.

What would the best way to go about this? Is there an SQL command that I could loop through in PHP to dig through the hundreds of DB tables?

I can get a list of the sites using the [`get_sites()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sites/) function and loop through that.

Or is there a better tool to export the database and find/replace there (the size of some of these DBs would crash atom/sublime/brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have (SSH) access to [WP CLI](http://wp-cli.org/), you can run this in your site root:

```
wp search-replace abc.multisite.com multisite.com/abc
```

For Multisites, if you want to search in all tables, you'll need the `--network` flag.

http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/

> By default, the command uses tables registered to the $wpdb object.
>   On multisite, this will just be the tables for the current site unless
>   --network is specified. Search/replace intelligently handles PHP serialized data, and does not change primary key values.

```
wp search-replace abc.multisite.com multisite.com/abc --network
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea WP-CLI existed. I've gotten the general idea of it and it seems to be mostly working (have a few issues when replacing site URLs still)

While I still have to figure out the nuances for my particular situation, I believe this is going to work perfectly for what I need - thanks!

Note: `wp --info` had no output for me, it turns out Suhosin needed to have an exception made for `wp-cli` and now it works like a dream. Thanks again!