# Wordpress crashes after migration

Tags: wordpress, migration, php-7.2

What did I:
Replaced filesystem to the new hosting. Replaced database;
Then I checked the new hosting and it still has been working.
Of course, any link led me to the old website,
so I could not even had access to the wordpress control panel. To solve it I changed links by executing following queries:

```
UPDATE "cms_wp_options"SET "option_value" = replace(option_value, "ppseminary.ru", "31.177.78.178")

UPDATE "cms_wp_posts"SET "guid" = replace(guid, "ppseminary.ru", "31.177.78.178")

UPDATE "cms_wp_posts"SET "post_content" = replace(post_content, "ppseminary.ru", "31.177.78.178")

UPDATE "cms_wp_nextend2_image_storage"

SET "image" = replace(image, "ppseminary.ru", "31.177.78.178")
```

After all I checked my new host and found it broken: any page returns the only error:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>hcfy-result.__hcfy__result__loaded__.__hcfy__result__both__{border: 1px dotted}</style>
   </head>
   <body>@font-face {
      font-family: 'oxana-tigra';
      src: url('/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/8054OxAna-TIGRA.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/8054OxAna-TIGRA.woff') format('woff');
      font-display: auto;
      }
      .oxana-tigra{font-family: 'oxana-tigra' !important;}
      Can't open file
   </body>
   <div style="all: initial;">
      <div style="all: initial;" id="__hcfy__"></div>
   </div>
</html>
```

I have no idea what else me to do. Finally I decided to check what if to automate migration with some wordpress plugin: I run duplicator pro but it shows too many issues while packaging: I very doubt it will work.
Any idea?

Comment: Locked Out of Your WordPress Dashboard?

Comment: In the new location - yes; In the old - I do not;

Comment: and you got a white screen?

Comment: You can't use a find replace in the database, since WP uses serialized arrays within the DB. You must use something like [wp cli search-replace](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) command using the WP CLI - or some kind of plugin that does a migration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Large scale database replace method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43080759/large-scale-database-replace-method)

Comment: I have answered your question I hope it will help you

Comment: Javier, white screen with following line:

@font-face { font-family: 'oxana-tigra'; src: url('/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/8054OxAna-TIGRA.woff2') format('woff2'), url('/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/8054OxAna-TIGRA.woff') format('woff'); font-display: auto; } .oxana-tigra{font-family: 'oxana-tigra' !important;} Can't open file

Answer (score 0):

With respect, the way you're using to migrate your site -- editing data in your database -- is almost impossible to do correctly. Most of the data in your `cms_wp_options` table, and much of it in other tables, is stored in a way that makes SQL `UPDATE ... REPLACE()` operations very difficult to get right. Use the https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/ plugin for that if you can even get to your new site.

You are far more likely to succeed with Duplicator Pro or another site migration plugin.  There are several good free ones. https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/site+migration/

Your time is better spent working through the issues that plugin complains about.

One tip: before you create a migration package, use a database cleaner plugin to get rid of unused data. I like Advanced Database Cleaner, but others will also work. https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/database%2Bcleaner/

One trick I've used with Duplicator, that helps with sites with a great many uploaded images and other media:  Exclude the wp_content/uploads folder when you create your package. Then create one or more zipfiles on your own to migrate that folder separately.

Comment: I checked that possibility and as had had expecting: it got worst, for my database is  overloaded (or for something else),  Duplicator Pro says "database does not exist" (of course it does, DP just wrote 31 tables there!).